# For a generative model, how is modelling p(X,Y) equivalent to modelling P(X|Y=y)?

Tags: machine-learning, discriminant-analysis, definition, generative-models

On the Wikipedia page for generative models it gives the following definitions of a generative model:

(X is an observable variable, Y is the target variable)
1)
A generative model is a model of the joint probability distribution p(X,Y).

2)
A generative model is a model of the conditional probability of the observable X, given a target y. Symbolically, p(X|Y=y).

My question is as follows:
Given that P(X,Y)=P(X|Y)P(Y), how is modelling P(X|Y) equivalent to modelling P(X,Y)?

What about P(Y)? Is there some tacit assumption that p(Y) can be obtained easily?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A generative model represents the full joint distribution $p(x,y)$. The conditional distribution $p(x \mid y)$ alone wouldn't be considered a generative model. The part where Wikipedia says this is inconsistent with standard terminology, and the citation Wikipedia gives for this statement doesn't actually support it.